# sample/tutorial of using selenium 2.0 web driver in .net?

Tags: asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

is there any tutorial/sample for using selenium 2.0 web driver with .net ?

I've tried searching but could find only java, nothing about .net and selenium 2.0 web driver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The docs here has an example in C#:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

class GoogleSuggest
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Notice navigation is slightly different than the Java version
        //This is because 'get' is a keyword in C#
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Cheese");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Page title is: " + driver.Title);
        driver.Quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download **latest package**: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Try here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

There is also documentation in the archive with .net bindings here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-dotnet-2.31.2.zip&can=2&q=label%3AFeatured

Hope it helps you