# UnitTest .Net with Ajax Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I need make some unit test or some kind of testing which make me help to every time easily to check all my forms are working correctly.

I am developing all application in .Net with c#. but with HTML controls only not a single .Net control.

Mostly work with jQuery Ajax for posting form.

How do I make some testing which help me for all validation. and all front validation is working good and database entry is going good.

Comment: I did not tried any things. I need some automatic tool or just done by one time so I can test next time by code. and it will return just result success or fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking more about doing automatic functional testing rather than unit testing to combine all of those aspects into a test. Take a look at the [Selenium Web Driver](http://nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver) as a mechanism to drive the testing.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187863/sample-tutorial-of-using-selenium-2-0-web-driver-in-net) of using Selenium with C#. You can combine that with a testing framework such as Nunit to assert that your tests are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is misleading. Unit testing is just for testing a single unit of code. You are trying to test the UI functionality. There is a firefox plugin called selenium and I think it will help you achive what you want.
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html